# mypy not found after pip installation

Tags: types, pip, mypy

I have installed mypy as instructed on the [Getting Started](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html) page (`python3 -m pip install mypy`).

When I try running `mypy program.py` as recommended, I get `zsh: command not found: mypy`.

`pip3 mypy` shows: `mypy    1.5.1`

If I run using `python3 -m mypy program.py`, it works.

How can I get the intended `mypy program.py` command to work?

Comment: `pip3 show --files mypy` and add the `bin/` directory to `$PATH` . Most probably the directory is `$HOME/.local/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears when you don't have a library in your system or project (virtual environment). Maybe you installed it on your system (globally) but you're trying to run a `mypy program.py` inside your virtual environment.

To enter your virtual environment write this in terminal inside your project: `source venv/bin/activate`